# How does ExecutionEngine class relate to MCJit and ORC?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm just starting to get acquainted with LLVM and I have been looking for information regarding the actual state of LLVM's JIT API and implentation. A lot of examples I had found, show [usage either of `ExecutionEngine` class](https://gist.github.com/tomas789/8162150) or MCJit/ORC API, but never show them in conjunction.

Therefore my question is: what exactly is the relation between `ExecutionEngine` class and MCJit/ORC API? Currently, my understanding is that `ExecutionEngine` is a kind of API class for both MCJit and ORC, hiding their implementation details. Is this correct? Can it be assumed that one should always use `ExecutionEngine` class instead of MCJit/ORC API? If so, why [official LLVM's tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT1.html) uses ORC API directly and doesn't even mention the existence of `ExecutionEngine` class? Is it just outdated?

Comment: I'd say they are orthogonal and you should use the one that fits your needs. The `ExecutionEngine` and `MCJIT` APIs are more stable, while ORC is still under active development and changes a lot. Depending on the version of LLVM you use there is also `LLJIT` interface. And yes, most of the relevant documentation is outdated.

Comment: @AlexDenisov Thanks. Can you highlight a couple of main differences between `ExecutionEngine` and `MCJIT`? Which use cases are more appropriate for one and another?

Comment: EE is supposed to be an abstraction, but its API nowadays is very similar to the MCJIT. I'd suggest you picking any and coming back with questions when you feel stuck :)